# Need to identify user by browser in python/django?

Tags: django, browser, notifications

I need to send notifications to all the users who follow a topic. I use the following model:

```
class FollowPage(TimeStampedModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_following_page', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
```

In the case, when user is not logged in, how do I store the browser info and send the notification to the browser. Should I create a new user by browser or change the model to follow the topic by browser?

Comment: I don't understand what the user's browser has to do with anything here.

Comment: You could send an email to the user, but if you want to push notifications to the user I suggest you take a look into WebSockets - and that requires work in both your frontend application as well as in the backend. I suggest [django-channels](https://github.com/django/channels).

Comment: @DanielRoseman, if the user is not login, we need to store the unique key per browser so as to send the notifications to the browser.

Comment: @henriquesalvaro, I'm using izooto for push notifications. When the user is not login, I generate a unique code using js which is stored for browser identity. But, when the user clicks on notification, I need to redirect him to a page. Then, I need browser info to send the required notifications. Can I somehow fetch the unique browser token in middleware or is there any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe consider creating notification model with boolean field 'is_read' and then send to user, only this unread?